# How to write JSON Schema for property depend on other filed's value?

Tags: jsonschema

Here is my request:  when num==0, a is required; when num==1, b is required.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "num": { "type": "integer" },
    "a": { "type": "string" },
    "b": { "type": "string" }
  }
  "required": [ "num" ]
}
```

Comment: I haven't found a solution for the value dependency.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {"$ref": "#/definitions/0"},
    {"$ref": "#/definitions/1"},
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "0": {
      "properties": {
        "num": {"enum": [0]},
        "a": {"type": "string"}
      },
      "required": ["num", "a"]
    },
    "1": {
      "properties": {
        "num": {"enum": [1]},
        "b": {"type": "string"}
      },
      "required": ["num", "b"]
    }
  } 
}
```

I am using [jsonschema](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema), it returns `is not exactly on from <#definitions/0>`. That's not what I want. I hope it can return message about the detail, like `a` is required.

Answer (score 0):

improved version:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "num": { "type": "integer" },
    "a": { "type": "string" },
    "b": { "type": "string" }
  }
  "required": [ "num" ],
  "dependencies": {
    "a": {
      "properties": {
        "num": {
          "enum": [0]
        }
      }
    },
    "b": {
      "properties": {
        "num": {
          "enum": [1]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```